# How to get existing database record into an GirdView for performing CRUD operations in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crud

I have a model class.

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Full name Required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public bool BulkUpdate { get; set; }


    }
}
```

I have a database table also populated with records. I want to implement an editable grid view control in MVC. How should i approach for this? It will be helpful if someone gives me an idea about the View.cshtml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, there are many 3rd party grid's that are available. I am giving you an example of a grid called [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) which is a nice grid to show your data and perform CRUD operations. I have also setup a sample repository for your case with Employee data. I hope this helps you out. The CRUD operations in the grid are performed on the `Controller` side. The link to the repository can be found [here](https://github.com/rahsharm77/JTableExample-.NET-MVC/tree/master/JTableExampleNETFramework).

Your code structure would look like:

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace JTableExampleNETFramework.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full name Required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public bool BulkUpdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JTableExampleNETFramework.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JTableExampleNETFramework.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Employee()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Added as an example to populate our dummy list for employee
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetEmployeeData()
        {
            try
            {
                //Add to our list
                List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>()
                {
                  new Employee(){ EmployeeId =1, Name ="Bill",City="New York",Department="HR",Gender="Male",BulkUpdate=false},
                  new Employee(){ EmployeeId =2, Name ="Lindsey",City="London",Department="Finance",Gender="Female",BulkUpdate=true},
                  new Employee(){ EmployeeId =3, Name ="Rahul",City="New Delhi",Department="IT",Gender="Male",BulkUpdate=false},
                  new Employee(){ EmployeeId =4, Name ="Sameera",City="Istanbul",Department="Operations",Gender="Female",BulkUpdate=true}
                };

                //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = employeeList, TotalRecordCount = employeeList.Count });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateEmployeeData()
        {
            //Your logic to update employee data
            return Json("Updated Employee Data");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteEmployeeData()
        {
            //Your logic to delete employee data
            return Json("Delete Employee Data");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult InsertEmployeeData()
        {
            //Your logic to insert employee data
            return Json("Insert Employee Data");
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "JTable Example";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-
requests">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link href="~/Scripts/jtable/Content/themes/metroblue/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jtable/Scripts/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jtable/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="EmployeeTableContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Starting to load the JTable Grid");
            $('#EmployeeTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Employees List',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '/Home/GetEmployeeData',
                    deleteAction: '/Home/DeleteEmployeeData',
                    updateAction: '/Home/UpdateEmployeeData',
                    createAction: '/Home/InsertEmployeeData'
                },
                fields: {
                    EmployeeId: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: true,
                        title: 'Employee ID',
                    },
                    Name : {
                        title: 'Employee Name'
                    },
                    City : {
                        title: 'City'
                    },
                    Department : {
                        title: 'Department'
                    },
                    Gender : {
                        title: 'Gender'
                    },
                    BulkUpdate : {
                        title: 'Is Bulk Update',
                        list: false,
                    },
                }
            });
            //Load student list from server
            $('#EmployeeTableContainer').jtable('load');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** In order to render this grid, please take the follwing CSS :

- jquery-ui.css
- jtable.css

and JS

- jquery.jtable.js

from the `Scripts` folder and refer them in your `View`.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your help!!